# Finding the best possible subset combinations of numbers to reach a given sum or closest to it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

So, I have this problem I need to solve, apparently this is called **Subset Sum Problem**, except I need to get the subset not only when is exact to the given number, but the closest in case there is no exact sum that reaches the given number, it shouldn’t go over the reference number, only below, also if there are more than two possible subsets with the same result, I'd like to get the subset with the better distribution, from the highest to lowest number in the array as preferred, and limiting each subset to not overpass 10 times the same number, repeating is allowed, for example:

Here is the array with the predefined values:

```
let num = [64.20, 107, 535, 1070];
```

and a given number:

```
let investment = 806.45
```

One possible solution would be:

```
[0, 2, 1, 0] // this sums up to 749 (since there is no way to get to 806.45 with the given array)
```

Please notice this result is referring to how many times each value in nums is allowed to reach the sum:

But a better solution would be:

```
[4, 5, 0, 0] // this sums up to 791.80 (since there is no way to get to 806.45 with the given array)
```

And an even better solution (because takes in consideration the higher values over the lower ones first)

```
[4, 0, 1, 0] // this sums up to 791.80 also but you can see it's taking a higher value when possible.
```

Another important restriction would be that should never give a negative result.

So far i have tried like this (in VueJS):

```
getPackages(){
      let investment = 806.45;
      const num = [64.20, 107, 535, 1070]
      let a, b, c, d;
      let results = [];

      a = investment / num[0] >= 0 ? (investment/num[0]) : 0;
      b = investment / num[1] >= 0 ? (investment/num[1]) : 0;
      c = investment / num[2] >= 0 ? (investment/num[2]) : 0;
      d = investment / num[3] >= 0 ? (investment/num[3]) : 0;

      let dResult = [], cResult = [], bResult = [], aResult = [];

      for (let i = 0; i <= d; i++){
        if (i>0){
          dResult.push((i * num[3]))
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i <= c; i++){
        if (i>0){
          cResult.push((i * num[2]))
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i <= b; i++){
        if (i>0){
          bResult.push((i * num[1]))
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i <= a; i++){
        if (i>0){
          aResult.push((i * num[0]))
        }
      }

      let aResultCoincidences = [];
      let bResultCoincidences = [];
      let cResultCoincidences = [];
      let dResultCoincidences = [];

      bResult.forEach(value => {
        aResult.findIndex(item => item === value) > 0 ? bResultCoincidences.push(aResult.findIndex(item => item === value)) : null
      })

      aResult.splice(0, Math.max(...bResultCoincidences) + 1)

      cResult.forEach(value => {
        bResult.findIndex(item => item === value) > 0 ? cResultCoincidences.push(bResult.findIndex(item => item === value)) : null
      })

      bResult.splice(0, Math.max(...cResultCoincidences) + 1)

      dResult.forEach(value => {
        cResult.findIndex(item => item === value) > 0 ? dResultCoincidences.push(cResult.findIndex(item => item === value)) : null
      })

      cResult.splice(0, Math.max(...dResultCoincidences) + 1)

      this.package1 = aResult.length
      this.package2 = bResult.length
      this.package3 = cResult.length
      this.package4 = dResult.length

    },
```

What happens in my approach is that I try to get all possible results from each multiplication, and then I remove the ones that matches between the arrays I made with this combination, to finally get the result, but this is not well optimized, and I'm sure there is probably a better solution to this problem.

Anyway ignore the vuejs implementation, that's only to set the values in the DOM.

***ES6 solution would be awesome.

CodeSandbox to play around: [CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-54h7y?file=/src/layout.vue:0-15583)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fun problem to think about. I looked up your Subset Sum problem and it's found to be NP-Complete. This is the hardest category of problems to solve, frequently just boiling down to brute force methods, so to be honest, when you say "I'm sure there is probably a better solution", it's possible there isn't and that this or other brute force methods like it are the only way to do it. But researching approaches to the root algorithm you already identified is your best bet to finding an optimal solution approach.

Comment: Are your sums supposed to be closest *without going over*?  Because all of these sum to  `813.20` (which is closer to `806.45` than is `791.8`): `[1, 2, 1, 0]`, `[1, 7, 0, 0]`, `[6, 4, 0, 0]`, and `[11, 1, 0, 0]`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet that’s a good observation! It should never go over.

Comment: This is not the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), this is the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Nevertheless, it's NP-complete. With a large number of items, getting the optimal solution may not be a realistic demand.

Comment: @Atmas "This is the hardest category of problems to solve." That appears to be a [common misconception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Common_misconceptions).

Comment: Ok. So the OP should look into knapsack solutions for inspiration as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach.  I didn't look yours over carefully, and don't know if this offers any advantages over it.

It is a brute-force approach, simply taking the cross-product of the potential individual values for each category, summing the totals, and then reducing the list to find all the options closest to the target.  I originally wrote this slightly differently, trying to capture the closest value whether over or under the target.

Here's an implementation with several helper functions:

```js
const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const crossproduct = (xss) => 
  xss.reduce((xs, ys) => xs.flatMap(x => ys.map(y => [...x, y])), [[]])

const range = (lo, hi) =>
  [...Array(hi - lo)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)

const call = (fn, ...args) => 
  fn (...args)

const closestSums = (t, ns) => 
  call (
    (opts = crossproduct (ns .map (n => range (0, 1 + Math .ceil (t / n))))) => 
      opts .map (xs => [xs, sum (xs .map ((x, i) => x * ns [i]))])
      .reduce (
        ({best, opts}, [opt, tot]) => 
          call (
            (diff = t - tot) => 
              diff >= 0 && diff < best
                ? {best: diff, opts: [opt]}
              : diff >= 0 && diff == best
                ? {best, opts: [...opts, opt]}
              : {best, opts}
          ),
          {best: Infinity, opts: []}
        ) .opts
  )

const byHigher = (as, bs) =>
  as .reduceRight ((r, _, i) => r || (as[i] < bs[i] ? 1 : as[i] > bs[i] ? -1 : 0), 0)

const closestCounts = (t, ns) => 
  closestSums (t * 100, ns .map (n => 100 * n)) 
    .filter (cs => cs.every(c => c <= 10))
    .sort (byHigher)

console .log (
  closestCounts (806.45, [64.20, 107, 535, 1070]),
  closestCounts (791.8, [64.20, 107, 535, 1070])  // exact match
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that the wrapper multiplies everything by 100 to rid us of decimals and the potential floating point rounding errors.  If that won't do, it would be easy enough to add some tolerance for matching.

The final sorting is naïve, assuming that your values are in ascending numeric order.  If not, that sorter would have to get more sophisticated.

As I said, this is not likely to be efficient, and it might not gain anything on your version, but it's at least a different approach.

Comment: This approach seems a lot better than mine, and it actually get's the better results so far, i know brute-force will make it harder to work on browsers after certain number quantity because possibilities would be huge considering it increases exponentially with the number of reference, but still it works for what i need, i don't need that large amounts... anyway i'm still wowndering if there is a way to reduce posibilities by descarting all others won't match the most repeated patron or result... so far so good one.

Comment: I'm quite certain that there are cleaner ways to eliminate long chains of unnecessary calculations.  For instance if `a0 * n0 + a1 * n1` is greater than our target, we don't have to consider any higher values for `a1` or any for `a2` or higher. But I don't have time now to think it through.

Comment: I understand, I have limited the max results from the filter, and I’m wondering if in your approach every subset at the end sums up to the same result?... I have done the sum on most and gives the same result, but not on all... just checking.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then yes, the results are all the options in the result end up at the same total (and if we can't do the multiply by 100, and have to introduce a tolerance, then they will be equal within that tolerance.)  We also filter out those with more than `10` in any component, and we sort to maximize the count of the rightmost numbers.

Comment: One more thing, somehow your approach is not considering the exact sum aswell, only if is closest... is there any part on the code where you define the rule in which the sum should be close but not the same? because it should be the same or the closest one in the case there is no exact sum. Thanks in advance for any hints, you can test this behavior by setting the reference value to 107 (which is one of the numbers in the array), it should return 0, 1, 0, 0, but it doesn't, but if you set the reference value to 108 for example, it will correctly return the right subset.

Comment: Yes, there was a bug where two instances of `diff > 0` really should have been `diff >= 0`.  It's fixed now.  But do watch out for issues with floating point rounding.  My multiplication by 100 is meant to help with that, but we might replace it with a check that the value is within some epsilon value of the target.

Comment: that’s perfect, thanks a lot! I tried but between diff and best, lol, worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Lets first consider the 2-varible case. We want to find two numbers x1, x2 such that

```
f(x1,x2) = 64.20 * x1 + 107 * x2 - 806.45
```

[image]

If we allow x1, x2 to be real numbers then this is just the equation of a line. In the problem we only want positive integer solutions, i.e. the grid points. I've badly drawn the grid points with those above the line in red and those below the line in blue. The problem is then finding grid point closest to the line.

Note that there are a lot of points we never need to consider, only the red and blue grid point are possible candidates.

[image]

Generating the coloured grid points is quite simple. We could loop through the x1 values from 0 to 13, calculate the real x2 value by solving the equation

```
x2 =  (806.45 - 64.20 * x1)/107
```

and finding the floor(x2) and ceil(x2). Slightly better is looping through the x2 which run from 0 to 8 solving for x1

```
x1 =  (806.45 - 107 * x2)/64.20.
```

Another approach might be some kind of zero following routine. If you are at a given grid point (x1,x2) calculate f(x1,x2) if it is less than 0 we need to consider (x1+1,x2) or (x1,x2+1), if f(x1,x2) is greater than zero consider (x1-1,x2) or (x1,x2-x1). I don't think the complication of this approach really brings any benefit.

If we now move to 3D, we have an equation in three variables, x1, x2, x3

```
f(x1,x2,x3) = 64.20 * x1 + 107 * x2 + 535 * x3 - 806.45
```

This defines a plane in 3D, requiring all variables to be non-negative restricts it to a triangular part of the plane.

[image]

To find candidate points here we could loop through possible interger pairs (x1,x2), then find the exact x3 value

```
x3 = (806.45 - 64.20 * x1 - 107 * x2)/ 535
```

and its floor and ceiling. The candidate (x1,x2) only line in a candidate triangle so we can use the following procedure.

```
// First find max possible x1

x1_max = ceil(806.45/64.20)
for(x1 = 0; x1< x1_max; ++x1) {
   // for a given x1 find the maximum x2
   x2_max = ceil((806.45 - 64.20*x1)/107)
   for(x2=0;x2<x2_max;++x2) {
       // for a given (x1,x2) find the exact x3
       x3 = (806.45 - 64.20 * x1 - 107 * x2)/ 535
       // and its floor and ceiling
       x3l = floor(x3); x3h = ceil(x3);
       add_to_candidates(x1,x2,x3l);
       add_to_candidates(x1,x2,x3h);
   }
}
```

Once you can candidates simply select the one with the smallest absolute value.

A similar idea would extend to more variables.

Comment: This seems seriously well analyzed, still and this is my own fault, it's a little hard to follow for my math  knowledge, and can't think of a way to reproduce it on javascript, or to extend it to the use case I'm posting since I'm considering 4 numbers... with that said, I'll give it a try and see what can I get... if I'm not misunderstanding your answer, this is more like an Algorithm than a brute force approach, I'm I right?